# Complex query join in ebean

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ebean

I have the following schema.

```
A(Aid, Aname)

B(Bid, Aid, Bname)

C(Cid, Bid, Cname)

B.Aid->A.Aid

C.Bid->B.Bid
```

I need to get the list of C.Cname to a given set of A.Aid s. I came up with this query.

```
SELECT C.Cname
FROM B,C
WHERE B.Bid = C.Bid AND B.Aid IN ('1','2','3')
```

I'm new to ebeans and I want to do this using ebeans. How can I do it? My models are as follows. I'm using mysql as my database.

```
class A
{
int Aid;
String Aname;
}

class B
{
int Bid;
A Aid;
String Bname;
}

class C
{
int Cid;
B Bid;
String Bname;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
class A {
   @Id
   int id;

   String name;
}

class B {
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne 
  A a;

  String name;
}

@Entity
class C {
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne
  B b;

  String name;
}
```

With correct Model, the next request can be work :

```
Ebean.find(C.class)  
    .fetch("b")  
    .fetch("b.a")  
    .where()
    .in("b.a.id", [1, 2, 3])
    .findList();
```